# Spark Error with Glue Worker G.1X but not with G.2X - Error Message: Could Not Execute Broadcast in 300 secs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have a Glue ETL job where I read hundreds/thousands of small (kB) files from s3 and a few tables from an RDS database and join these together and make some other transformations such as grouping and aggregating count, first and min of some columns.

The output data frame has the correct format that I want but when I move the script from my local computer to AWS Glue and try to execute the job with the complete dataset (from s3 and the database) I ***sometimes*** get an error:

Setup 1:

- Worker type: G.1X
- Number of workers: 10
- Run status: **Failed**
- Error: *An error occurred while calling o495.parquet. Could not execute broadcast in 300 secs. You can increase the timeout for broadcast via spark.sql.broadcastTimeout or disable broadcast join by setting spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold to -1*

Setup 2:

- Worker type: G.2X
- Number of workers: 5
- Run status: **Succeeded**

Why do I get this error when using the G.1X worker type and not G.2X?
What does the ***broadcastTimeout*** and ***autoBroadcastJoinTreshold*** mean in this case?

In my code I do the following when I join dataframes together:

1. ```
   df3 = df.join(df2, ['a'])
   ```
2. ```
   df5 = df3.join(df4, ['c', 'd'])
   ```

And I therefore never explicitly broadcast the data frame like:

```
dfX = df.join(broadcast(df2), ['a'])
```

Will the job still try to perform a broadcast join which somehow forces it to run out of memory and therefore runs better with the G.2X worker type? Just a theory from my side.

Thank you in advance!